# How to get user information while logging in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I want to store some user information related to the user id from a firebase user. I want to do this as I log in, but for some reason the user is not created, I tried to read about this but I can not find the same problem, i added .then() to the function but it still does not work. What am i not getting right?

```
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, 
    this.state.password).then((user) => {
      Username = this.state.username;
      this.sendUserinfo(Username,user.uid);
    }).
    catch((error) => {
      console.log("HJÄÄÄLP" ,error);
    });
  }
```

When i console.log the result i get undefined and i do not get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

signInWithEmailAndPassword. Does not return the user object. Thats why you are not able to use it.

If you want to get the information about the logged in user. For example its id. You can check the auth state.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // This will trigger when user logs in.
    console.log(user.uid);
  }
});
```